# Multiple file upload rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4. I want to upload multiple files of type doc, doc.x, pdf etc, but not any image file. I implemented  'jquery-fileupload-rails' gem. But while uploading it shows "Internal Server Error".

Can you help me with this issue? Or is there any other way to upload multiple files of above mentioned file type?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the gem `Papaerclip` available in rails for uploading images and files of any type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the other responses, you're going to need to use an attachment-handling gem, such as [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

The problem you have is that although the `JQuery upload` gem is working to send files to your server, Rails doesn't know how to handle the files you send, hence why you're seeing the `500` error

---

**Paperclip**

We love Paperclip - it's perfect for uploading any attachment to your server

Here's how to use it:

```
#GemFile
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.5.2"


#app/models/attachment.rb
Class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :attachment
end


#db/migrate
def change
    create_table :attachments do |t|
         t.attachment :attachment
         t.timestamps
    end
end

#app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb
def new 
    @attachment = Attachment.new
end

def create
    @attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)
    @attachment.save
end

private
def attachment_params
     params.require(:attachment).permit(:attachment)
end

#app/views/attachments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @attachment, {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: This is working for single upload of a file. But I need to upload multiple files at once.